# Illustrator blend with different blending modes issue

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending, blend-modes

I have a star with 2 layers se to Normal and one set to Overlay

[image]

[image]

the layer in Overlay is a white/black gradient with black set to 0 opacity

[image]

[image]

Now, the issue appears when I blend two stars together, where I get this result

[image]

The Overlay layers still keep their blending mode without giving the same result as the original object

Why is that? Is there a solution to get a blend with object that look like the non-blended ones?

Edit:
I tried to flatten the transparency using this settings

[image]

But what I get after blending again the objects is this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fast and easy way: convert your star as a Symbol!

[image: symbol]

Answer (score 1):

<del>I don't think there's a way to get it to work and keep the blending modes intact</del><sup>*</sup>. You can flatten your artwork though. *Before* creating your blend, select your star (or at least the objects with blending modes and the objects they blend with) and go to:

> *Object → Flatten Transparency...*

That will remove (or flatten) any blending modes or transparency whilst keeping the artwork visually the same... You can then use blend with no issues.

<sup>*</sup> [Use a symbol](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/86562/52050)

Comment: I already tried to do that but the result wasn't good either, I'll edit my question to post the result with this method

Comment: Looks like the problem part is being flattened to an image maybe? Anyway, see the other answer, that'll do it :)